# How to implement file locking for linux in java

Tags: java, linux, filelock

In my project a a process is creating a file and different process of other software reading that file.As file is created the other process reads it even the size of file is 0.I want to implement the locking mechanism on file for linux because filechannel lock is working in windows but not in Linux.So please suggest me the solution.

Comment: You can create a MyAppLockfile  on ~/tmp/ while your process build the file. If it finish the creation operation you have to remove the lockfile On your process that read that file, you have to verify the lockfile's existence. If it exists, your file creator process still building the file. If the lockfile not exists, it means that your file is ready.

Comment: Define 'not working in Linux' Are you aware that Linux file locks are advisory only by default, and only affect other programs using locks?